# What is the purpose of uint64_t ps_pledge varibale in OpenBSD kernel code?

Tags: c, kernel, openbsd

I am playing with OpenBSD kernel code, especially this file `sys/kern/sched_bsd.c`.

```
    void
    schedcpu(void *arg)
    {
......

......

    LIST_FOREACH(p, &allproc, p_list) {
        /*
         * Increment sleep time (if sleeping). We ignore overflow.
         */
        if (p->p_stat == SSLEEP || p->p_stat == SSTOP)
            p->p_slptime++;
        p->p_pctcpu = (p->p_pctcpu * ccpu) >> FSHIFT;
        /*
         * If the process has slept the entire second,
         * stop recalculating its priority until it wakes up.
         */
        if (p->p_slptime > 1)
            continue;
        SCHED_LOCK(s);
        /*
         * p_pctcpu is only for diagnostic tools such as ps.
         */
....

....
```

> ```
> LIST_FOREACH(TYPE *var, LIST_HEAD *head, LIST_ENTRY NAME);
> The macro LIST_FOREACH traverses the list referenced by head in the forward direction, assigning each element in turn to var.
> ```

Now, here, `p` will contain the address of `struct proc` structure of eery process which is in the file

> sys/sys/proc.h

Now, again, this structure contains another `struct process *p_p` structure, which denotes the properties of every process like its `pid`, `flags`, `threads` etc.

```
    struct proc {
        TAILQ_ENTRY(proc) p_runq;
        LIST_ENTRY(proc) p_list;    /* List of all threads. */

        struct  process *p_p;       /* The process of this thread. */
        TAILQ_ENTRY(proc) p_thr_link;   /* Threads in a process linkage. */

        TAILQ_ENTRY(proc) p_fut_link;   /* Threads in a futex linkage. */
        struct  futex   *p_futex;   /* Current sleeping futex. */

        /* substructures: */
        struct  filedesc *p_fd;     /* copy of p_p->ps_fd */
        struct  vmspace *p_vmspace; /* copy of p_p->ps_vmspace */
#define p_rlimit    p_p->ps_limit->pl_rlimit

    ....

    ....
```

Now, stucture `struct process` contains `uint64_t ps_plegde`.

```
struct process {
    /*
     * ps_mainproc is the original thread in the process.
     * It's only still special for the handling of p_xstat and
     * some signal and ptrace behaviors that need to be fixed.
     */
    struct  proc *ps_mainproc;
    struct  ucred *ps_ucred;    /* Process owner's identity. */

....

....

    u_short ps_acflag;      /* Accounting flags. */

    uint64_t ps_pledge;
    uint64_t ps_execpledge; 

....

....
```

Now, I wrote some modification in `void schedcpu()` function code.

```
void
schedcpu(void *arg)
{
    pid_t pid;
    uint64_t pledge_bit;
....

....


    LIST_FOREACH(p, &allproc, p_list) {

    pid=p->p_p->pid;
    pledge_bit=p->p_p->ps_pledge;

    if (pledge_bit) {
            printf("pid: %10d pledge_bit: %10llu pledge_xbit:%10llx\n",pid,pledge_bit,pledge_bit);
}

        /*
         * Increment sleep time (if sleeping). We ignore overflow.
         */
        if (p->p_stat == SSLEEP || p->p_stat == SSTOP)
            p->p_slptime++;
        p->p_pctcpu = (p->p_pctcpu * ccpu) >> FS 
....

....
```

> Here, **Kernel log**

```
pid:      37846 pledge_bit:     393359 pledge_xbit:      6008f
pid:      96037 pledge_bit:     393544 pledge_xbit:      60148
pid:      86032 pledge_bit:     264297 pledge_xbit:      40869
pid:      72264 pledge_bit:     393480 pledge_xbit:      60108
pid:      40102 pledge_bit:          8 pledge_xbit:          8
pid:        841 pledge_bit: 2148162527 pledge_xbit:   800a5bdf
pid:      49970 pledge_bit: 2148096143 pledge_xbit:   8009588f
pid:      68505 pledge_bit:         40 pledge_xbit:         28
pid:      46106 pledge_bit:         72 pledge_xbit:         48
pid:      77690 pledge_bit:     537161 pledge_xbit:      83249
pid:      44005 pledge_bit:     262152 pledge_xbit:      40008
pid:      82731 pledge_bit: 2148096143 pledge_xbit:   8009588f
pid:      71609 pledge_bit:     262472 pledge_xbit:      40148
pid:      54330 pledge_bit:     662063 pledge_xbit:      a1a2f
pid:      77764 pledge_bit:    1052776 pledge_xbit:     101068
pid:        699 pledge_bit: 2148096143 pledge_xbit:   8009588f
pid:      84265 pledge_bit:    1052776 pledge_xbit:     101068

....

....
```

Now, Is that possible to know which process pledge what permissions, from looking at pledge_bit (decimal or hex values) that I got from above output?

I took pledge hex value of dhclient process i.e `0x8009588f`, then, I wrote a sample hello world program with `pledge("STDIO",NULL);` and again I looked at dmesg and got same pledge_bit for hello world i.e `0x8009588f`.

Then, this time I looked at dhclient source code and found out that, dhclient code pledged `pledge("stdio inet dns route proc", NULL)`.

But, then, how is it possible to get same pledge hex bit for different pledge parameters?

Comment: Probably the question is too specific for SO, ask in tech@openbsd.org.

Comment: yeah, I also think so.
Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my answer after reading source code again and again.

So, I just want to contribute my learning so that future developers won't face any problem regarding this issue or confusion.

**First understanding:**

I wrote hello world like this,

```
void
main() {
pledge("STDIO", NULL);   /* wrong use of pledge call */
printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

Correction of above code:

```
void
main() {

if (pledge("stdio", NULL) == -1) {
        printf("Error\n");
}
printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

I forgot to check the return value from pledge().

**Second understanding:**

`dhclient.c` code contains pledge() call as:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct ieee80211_nwid    nwid;
    struct ifreq         ifr;
    struct stat      sb;
    const char      *tail_path = "/etc/resolv.conf.tail";
....

....


fork_privchld(ifi, socket_fd[0], socket_fd[1]);

....

....


    if ((cmd_opts & OPT_FOREGROUND) == 0) {
        if (pledge("stdio inet dns route proc", NULL) == -1)
            fatal("pledge");
    } else {
        if (pledge("stdio inet dns route", NULL) == -1)
            fatal("pledge");
    }

....

....

void
fork_privchld(struct interface_info *ifi, int fd, int fd2)
{
    struct pollfd    pfd[1];
    struct imsgbuf  *priv_ibuf;
    ssize_t      n;
    int      ioctlfd, routefd, nfds, rslt;

    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        fatal("fork");
        break;
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
....

....

}
```

Now, I wrote sample hello world code which contains the same parameters as dhclient:

```
void
main() {

if(pledge("stdio inet proc route dns", NULL) == -1) {
        printf("Error\n");
}

while(1) {}
}
```

Now, I tested this above sample hello world code and got pledge_bit as `0x101068` in hex, which is correct.

But, as I told you earlier in my question, I became confused, when I saw different pledge_bit for `dhclient`. Because, as you guys know that both have same parameters in their pledge().

Then, how is it possible?

Now, here is the catch,

After continuously looking at dhclient source code, I found one function named as `fork_privchld()`.

This function called before pledging in dhclient, so, it's like there is no pledge for this function as it is called before pledging.

So, just for verification again I wrote sample hello world code, but this time without any pledge() syscall.

```
void
main() {
printf("hello\n");
}
```

And, guess what, I got the same pledge_bit as `0x8009588f`.

So, after this verification, it is verified that `fork_privchld()` function doesn't have any pledge bit set because as it is called before pledging in `dhclient`.

This function creates a [priv] child process for dhclient.

```
# ps aux|grep dhclient
root     26416  0.0  0.1   608   544 ??  Is     8:36AM    0:00.00 dhclient: em0 [priv] (dhclient)
_dhcp    33480  0.0  0.1   744   716 ??  Isp    8:36AM    0:00.00 dhclient: em0 (dhclient)
```

And, I don't know why I was only looking at the first process i.e `[priv] (dhclient)`. This process is the one which is created by `fork_privchld()` function.

That's why this process has `0x8009588f` pledge bit (due to called before pledging, so, no pledging at this point).

And, when I checked the second process i.e `_dhcp`, then I got my expected pledge_bit i.e `0x101068` (due to pledging).

**So, I hope things will clear after reading this.**

***Note: Please, feel free to update me, if anything I forgot or missed.***